# Select inside DataFlow, MySQL source

Tags: mysql, ssis

I copy a table, MySQL (ado net) -> SQL (ole db).
At first I coppied it completely but since it contains millions of fields and I just need half of them I thought of just copying what I need instead of the copying the entire table.

Problem is I can't find the correct sentence for making it work.
Here's a pic of the full copy so you can see how it appears in the source.

[image]

So, instead of **Table or View** I've tried the **SQL Command**. Select field1, field2 from "" where field1 = 'AA' but it wouldn't work. I'm getting confused by the "". Is that some MySQL that I'm missing?

Comment: Your table name should go in place of the `""`.

Comment: So you say: Select field1, field2 from telepromdb.logllamados where field1 = 'AA'  it's not working like that. "query execution was interrupted (MySql.Data)"

Comment: Write your query and get it working in something like PHPmyadmin or whatever the tool is called. Then paste it into the ADO.NET source. Your query there might need to be `Select field1, field2 from ``telepromdb.logllamados`` where field1 = 'AA'`  Only one tick mark (thing above the tab key on US kbd) not two as my query shows and then one after the table name <kbd>`</kbd>

Comment: Tick marks are optional, if you use them, enclose the schema and table separately, e.g., \`telpromdb\`.\`logllamados\`.